# How to filter and restructure json data with php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I couldn't find an answer, so I decided to ask.

I get this response from an API:

```
[
  {
      "seasonNumber":1,
      "numWins":1,
      "numHighBracket":2,
      "numLowBracket":2,
      "seasonXp":111,
      "seasonLevel":5,
      "bookXp":0,
      "bookLevel":1,
      "purchasedVIP":false
   },
   {
      "seasonNumber":2,
      "numWins":1,
      "numHighBracket":21,
      "numLowBracket":31,
      "seasonXp":1651,
      "seasonLevel":25,
      "bookXp":9,
      "bookLevel":11,
      "purchasedVIP":false
   },
   {
      "seasonNumber":3,
      "numWins":9,
      "numHighBracket":57,
      "numLowBracket":127,
      "seasonXp":4659,
      "seasonLevel":68,
      "bookXp":0,
      "bookLevel":100,
      "purchasedVIP":true
   },
   {
      "seasonNumber":4,
      "numWins":8,
      "numHighBracket":19,
      "numLowBracket":36,
      "seasonXp":274,
      "seasonLevel":33,
      "bookXp":7,
      "bookLevel":35,
      "purchasedVIP":true
   }
]
```

I am trying to change the json data to this:

```
{
  "seasons":
    [
      {
        "season":1,
        "battle_pass":false
      },
      {
        "season":2,
        "battle_pass":false
      },
      {
        "season":3,
        "battle_pass":true
      },
      {
        "season":4,
        "battle_pass":true
      }
    ]
}
```

In my current code I am using regex like this:

```
preg_match_all("/(?:\{\"seasonNumber\"\:(\w)|purchasedVIP\"\:(\w+))/", $response, $seasons);

echo '{"seasons":'.json_encode($seasons, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).'}';
```

It's basically putting everything in a separate array but that's not what I want.

Comment: Decode json to array and filter this array.

Comment: Don't hack a json string with regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decode the json, restructure the data, re-encode.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kcCsi))

```
// your $json = 
foreach (json_decode($json) as $set) {
    $array[] = ["season" => $set->seasonNumber, "battle_pass" => $set->purchasedVIP];
}
echo json_encode(["seasons" => $array]);
```

Output:

```
{"seasons":[{"season":1,"battle_pass":false},{"season":2,"battle_pass":false},{"season":3,"battle_pass":true},{"season":4,"battle_pass":true}]}
```

---

p.s. if you want to force objects and pretty print, separate those flags with a pipe (`|`). https://3v4l.org/qsPb0

Comment: That is an insanely long portion of json and my phone is a poor tool to handle it. After decoding your json, save the array as a variable. You might like to use `$array = json_decode($json, true);` so that you can use array syntax (instead of object arrows). Then print out what is in the array, with `var_export($array);`. Now you will see the first level keys that are available -- like `profileChanges`. If you want to drill down that subarray, edit your `var_export()` call to be `var_export($array["profileChanges"]);` and run your file again. Keep drilling until you reach the desired subarray.

Comment: Keep adding the targeted keys after `$array` using square bracket syntax like `var_export($array["key1"]["key2"]["etc"])`.

Comment: oof man thanks for helping I'll try. if I'll have any issues I'll ask you

Comment: Ok so I have this code
`$response2_decocded = json_decode($response2, true);
   foreach ($response2['profileChanges']['stats']['attributes']['past_seasons'] as $set) {
    $array_seasons[] = ["season" => $set['seasonNumber'], "battle_pass" => $set['purchasedVIP']];
   }
   echo json_encode(["seasons" => $array_seasons]);`

And the response is `{"seasons":null}`

Comment: Your input string was too big for my preferred demo site, so I left out the json declaration.  I did test my code on my localhost host to be effective though.  https://3v4l.org/p4cMO  I have included  some `array_key()` calls to show you another simple way to investigate the array tree structure.  You were pretty close.  Good luck.